# How do I keep capitalization I put in? My Galaxy S7 switches it to lower case

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s7

If I capitalize in a text message, my Galaxy S7 changes it to lower case.  It works fine with most names, etc. and leaves the upper case, but common words, like Stone Mountain (a town in GA), it keeps changing the s and the m to lower case.  Same problem with Piper my dog.  Note:  This is NOT the first letter of a text problem - I've found that the spurious space at the beginning of the message causes that.

Comment: Are you saying that as soon as you write the word, it goes back to being lower case? Or is it that every time you type, you want it to automatically go to upper case? Is it autocorrect that's causing problems? Please include which keyboard you're using.

Comment: Yes, as soon as I type it, it goes back to lower case. I'm using Swype with autocorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Being that autocorrect is on, your keyboard will naturally change words to lower case when it sees fit. Being that the examples you gave, are regular words which are written in lower case,  the keyboard will not differentiate between the times that you mean to write the name of a city or just an English word. As for your dogs name, i would imagine that you wrote it once and now it's saved in lower case

Here are two things to try:

**Add the upper case word to your keyboard dictionary.**
To add a word to your Swipe keyboard, all you have to do is write the word a few times, and the keyboard will get used to it.

In your case you should type the word 'Stone' in upper case, and before you press on the space bar, press on the word on the suggestion bar where the word appears in orange font (as shown in the screenshot). Do this 2-3 time for each word. This way the keyboard will "learn" the word, and will not correct it next time.

[image]

**Remove the lower case word from the keyboard dictionary.**
Type the word in question, then before pressing the space bar, long press on the word in the suggestion bar and select 'remove'. After successfully removing the word from the dictionary write it again in upper case, and you should have an option to add it to the dictionary. If there is no such option, then write the word a few times in upper case till the keyboard 'learns' that this is how you want it.

Note: from now on, when you write the word mountain it will automatically turn into upper case even if you didn't mean to write the name of the city.

Hope this helps.